# Split arguments out of a fully qualified method name

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm parsing out the compiled XML docs that are generated when we compile our app. I have a member that looks like this:

```
<member name="M:Core.CachedType.GetAttributes(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Func{System.Attribute,System.Boolean})">
    <summary>
    <para>
    Gets all of the attributes for the Type that is associated with an optional property and optionally filtered.
    </para>
    </summary>
    <param name="property">The property.</param>
    <param name="predicate">The predicate.</param>
    <returns>Returns a collection of Attributes</returns>
</member>
```

In order to get the MethodInfo through reflection, I have to pass the Type parameters in to the [Type.GetMethodInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fed8f59(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This requires me to split the arguments up and fetch their Types. Initially this was easy enough, I was doing the following (using an example member string):

```
string elementName = "M:Core.CachedType.GetAttributes(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Func{System.Attribute,System.Boolean})";
string[] methodSignature = elementName.Substring(2, elementName.Length - 3).Split('(');
string methodName = methodSignature[0].Split('.').LastOrDefault();
string[] methodParameters = methodSignature[1].Split(',');
```

In this example, `methodSignature` contains two values

- Core.CachedType.GetAttributes
- System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Func{System.Attribute,System.Boolean}

This gives me the method name itself, and then the list of parameters that it can take. The `methodParameters` array contained each parameter by the method argument separating comma. This worked great initially, until I ran into Types that had more than 1 generic argument. The generic argument is separated by a comma as well, this obviously leads to unintended side-effects. In the example above, `methodParameters` contains

- System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
- System.Func{System.Attribute
- System.Boolean}

As you can see, it's split the `Func<Attribute, bool>` Type into two different elements in the array. I need to avoid this. I assume this means not using `string.Split`, which is fine. Is there an existing means to handle this that I'm not thinking of in .Net, or will I need to write a small parser to handle this?

Comment: smells like a job for regex

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a skill-set I am lacking in :/

Comment: @pm100: No; you can't parse nested braces in regex.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to créate a custom parser that can deal with nested braces. Something along the following line:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetParameterNames(string signature)
{
    var openBraces = 0;
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in signature)
    {
        if (c == '{')
        {
            openBraces++;
        }
        else if (c == '}')
        {
            openBraces--;
        }
        else if (c == ',' && openBraces == 0)
        {
            if (buffer.Length == 0)
                throw new FormatException(); //syntax is not right.

            yield return buffer.ToString();
            buffer.Clear();
            continue;
        }

        buffer.Append(c);
    }

    if (buffer.Length == 0 || openBraces != 0)
        throw new FormatException(); //syntax is not right.

    yield return buffer.ToString();
}
```

This is written on my cell pone so its bound to have errors, but you should get the idea. You can recursively call this to parse nested type lists.